# malloc() is returning the same address multiple times, even when I haven't used free()

Tags: c, pthreads, malloc

EDIT: I did use free(), ignore the title.

The gist is that every time `malloc()` is called, the address **0x8403620**
is returned, which I found out using Gdb.

```
tellers[i] = create_teller(0, i, NULL);
```

I first use `malloc()` on line 72 to create 3 teller structures. The first addressed returned, visible through Gdb, is **0x84003620**. The second is
**0x84033a0**, the third **0x84034e0**. Everything seems fine.

```
clients[i] = create_client(0, i, -1, -1);
```

Then I use `malloc()` on line 77 with the `create_client(`) function to 
create 100 clients. The first address, assigned to client[0], is ...
**0x8403620**. The same as tellers[0]. It gets worse. The next address
returned from `malloc()` is **0x8403620** again for when i = 1, and so 
on for i = 3, 4, ..., 99.

It isn't inherently the `create_client()` or the `create_teller()` functions, but
instead the `malloc()` function itself.

This is simply a very odd situation.

***Now, I'd like to ask***: Am I using `malloc()` wrong? Or is my version of `malloc()` bugged and should I somehow reinstall whatever it is? It's most likely my code since it works for creating the tellers, just not for the clients.

Here is the full code:

```c
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <assert.h>


typedef struct teller teller_t;
typedef struct client client_t;

teller_t *  create_teller (pthread_t thread_id, int id, client_t *assigned_client);
client_t *  create_client (pthread_t thread_id, int id, int operation, int amount);
void *      run_teller (void *arg);
void *      run_client (void *arg);

/* types of operations */
#define DEPOSIT     0
#define WITHDRAW    1

#define NUM_TELLERS 3
#define NUM_CLIENTS 100

struct client {
    pthread_t thread_id;

    int id;
    int operation;
    int amount;
};

struct teller {
    pthread_t thread_id;

    int id;
    bool available;
    client_t *assigned_client;
};

client_t *clients[100];
teller_t *tellers[3];

/* only 2 tellers at a time can access */
sem_t safe;
/* only 1 teller at a time can access */
sem_t manager;
/* amount of tellers available, at most 3 */
sem_t line; /* rename to available? */
/* each teller waiting for a client to be assigned to them */
sem_t wait_for_client[3];


int
main (int argc, char **argv) {
    (void) argc; 
    (void) argv;

    srand(time(NULL));

    /* This also tells us how many clients have been served */
    int client_index = 0;

    sem_init(&safe, 0, 2);
    sem_init(&manager, 0, 1);
    sem_init(&line, 0, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
        sem_init(&wait_for_client[i], 0, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TELLERS; i++) {
        tellers[i] = create_teller(0, i, NULL);
        pthread_create(&tellers[i]->thread_id, NULL, run_teller, (void *) tellers[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CLIENTS; i++) {
        clients[i] = create_client(0, i, -1, -1);
        pthread_create(&clients[i]->thread_id, NULL, run_client, (void *) clients[i]);
    }

    /* DEBUG
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CLIENTS; i++) {
        printf("client %d has id %d\n", i, clients[i]->id);
    }
    */

    // No threads should get past this point!!!
    // ==------------------------------------==

    // Should all of this below be handled by the clients instead of main?

    while (1) {
        if (client_index >= NUM_CLIENTS) {
            // TODO:
            // tell tellers that there are no more clients 
            // so they should close, then then close the bank.

            break;
        }

        sem_wait(&line);

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (tellers[i]->available) {
                int client_id = clients[client_index]->id;

                //printf("client_index = %d\n", client_index); // DEBUG

                tellers[i]->assigned_client = clients[client_index++];
                tellers[i]->available = false;


                printf(
                    "Client %d goes to Teller %d\n", 
                    client_id, 
                    tellers[i]->id
                );

                sem_post(&wait_for_client[i]);

                break;
            }
        }

        //sem_post(&line); // Is this needed?
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}


teller_t *  
create_teller (pthread_t thread_id, int id, client_t *assigned_client) {
    teller_t *t = (teller_t *) malloc(sizeof(teller_t));
    if (t == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: Unable to allocate teller_t.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    t->thread_id = thread_id;
    t->id = id;
    t->available = true;
    t->assigned_client = assigned_client;

    return t;
}

/* TODO: Malloc returns the same address everytime, fix this */
client_t *  
create_client (pthread_t thread_id, int id, int operation, int amount) {
    client_t *c = malloc(sizeof(client_t));

    if (c == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: Unable to allocate client_t.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    c->thread_id = thread_id;
    c->id = id;
    c->operation = operation;
    c->amount = amount;

    return c;
}


void *
run_teller (void *arg) {
    teller_t *t = (teller_t *) arg;

    printf("Teller %d is available\n", t->id);

    while (1) {
        /* tell the line that a teller is available */
        sem_post(&line); 
        /* pass when the line assignes a client to this teller */
        sem_wait(&wait_for_client[t->id]); 

        assert(t->assigned_client != NULL);

        if (t->assigned_client->operation == WITHDRAW) {

        }
        else {

        }
    }

    free(arg);

    pthread_cancel(t->thread_id);
    return NULL;
}


void *
run_client (void *arg) {
    client_t *c = (client_t *) arg;

    c->operation = rand() & 1;

    printf(
        "Client %d waits in line to make a %s\n", 
        c->id, 
        ((c->operation == DEPOSIT) ? "Deposit" : "Withdraw")
    );

    free(arg);

    pthread_cancel(c->thread_id);
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Your code was dropped on the way to SO. :)

Comment: What is SO? I apologize, I don't understand what you mean. (edit: StackOverflow...)

Comment: I understand now, I had to edit my code in because of formatting issues. Sorry.

Comment: You should check `create_teller()` and `create_client()` return values. Furthermore: can you place a log pring just after `free(arg);` in run functions? Maybe if you can attach a log of an execution for a simplified version of your program (limited number of clients) it will be easier to undrestand what's going on.

Comment: The addresses I mentioned above were the return values of the functions `create_teller()` and `create_client()`. Also, what should I log/print after `free(arg);`? Also, I changed `free(arg);` to `free(c);` and `free(t);` since it would free a void * otherwise. That might be the problem. I'll get back to you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Then I use malloc() on line 77 with the create_client() function to create 100 clients.

Not exactly, you create one object, then you spawn a thread that manages that object, `run_client()` and then repeat. But `run_client()` basically does nothing except `free()` your client object! So `malloc` is totally right returning the same address again, as it is now free memory.

It just happens that your client threads are faster than your main one. Your problem here is that you are freeing the objects from secondary threads while leaving the dangling pointers in the global pointer array. If you use that array for debugging purposes, then nothing is actually wrong here, but if you want to use the client objects somewhen in the future, then you should not `free` your clients in the first place.

Comment: This is totally the case, thank you. I suppose I assumed `malloc()` would give me unique memory addresses. Thanks Rodrigo, Marc, and Sourav for the help!